# Word VBA code to close a word file leaves a blank Word Application

Tags: vba, file, ms-word

I have tried several options to just simply close my current word file after saving it, but each way I end up with Word itself open with a blank word application with no file shown.

My VBA code is running from an open word file. It then opens a second file, does some manipulations that all work. The problem may be with the way I open or close the file?

Here are the code segments:

```
CodeFile = ActiveDocument.FullName
```

which is the current file that contains the VBA Code.

Then I open another wordfile with this code

```
OpenwdFile (SurveyData)

Sub OpenwdFile(wdfile1 As String)

    Dim objWord As Object
    'Dim wdfile As String
    
    'We need to continue through errors since if Word isn't
    'open the GetObject line will give an error
    On Error Resume Next
    Set objWord = GetObject(, "Word.Application")

    'We've tried to get Word but if it's nothing then it isn't open
    If objWord Is Nothing Then
        Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    End If

    'It's good practice to reset error warnings
    On Error GoTo 0

    'Open your document and ensure its visible and activate after openning
    objWord.Documents.Open wdfile1
    'objWord.Visible = True
    objWord.Activate

    Set objWord = Nothing
End Sub
```

And finally at the end I try to save and close files, and hopefully the Word application. You can see the commented sections of what I have tried but none worked for me.

```
Closeup:
' Close the Survey Data File
    Documents(SurveyData).Close
    
' Save and close this file
    
    ActiveDocument.Close SaveChanges:=wdSaveChanges
    
'Actual handling of unsaved documents omitted from this answer
'If savedAllDocuments Or UserDoesNotCare Then
'    Application.Quit wdDoNotSaveChanges
'    Dim doc As Document
'    For Each doc In Application.Documents
'        doc.Close SaveChanges:=False
'        doc.Quit
'    Next doc
'End If
    
    
    


'Dim wdApp As New Word.Application, wdDoc As Word.Document
'With wdApp
  
'    Set wdDoc = .Documents.Open(FileName:=CodeFile, AddToRecentFiles:=False)
'        With wdDoc
'            .Close SaveChanges:=True
'        End With
'    .Quit
'End With

Application.Quit _
 SaveChanges:=wdSaveChanges, OriginalFormat:=wdWordDocument
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The core issue is that when you call `ActiveDocument.Close SaveChanges:=wdSaveChanges`, assuming `ActiveDocument` is the document with the running code (which is sounds like based on your question), then code in that document will stop running ... it is closed, afterall ... and so the `Application.Quit SaveChanges:=wdSaveChanges, OriginalFormat:=wdWordDocument` line will never be called hence you are left looking at Word with no open documents.

To fix, replace the `ActiveDocument.Close SaveChanges:=wdSaveChanges` lines with `ActiveDocument.Save` and then allow the `Application.Quit SaveChanges:=wdSaveChanges, OriginalFormat:=wdWordDocument` line to run.

Separately, your `OpenwdFile` Sub looks like the code you would use to get/start Word, and open a Document, if you were doing so from another application (eg Excel) ... if your code is running from within Word, you already have the Word application object and so don't need to use `GetObject` and `CreateObject`.

The entire `OpenwdFile` Sub can be replaced with this line `Documents.Open wdfile1`, however, it can be adjusted to get a reference to the opened 'wdfile1' document which should make your subsequent manipulations simpler and less bug-prone eg

```
Dim doc As Document
Set doc = Documents.Open(wdfile1) ' doc is now a reference to the opened 'wdfile1' document

' do your manipulations

doc.Close SaveChanges:=wdSaveChanges
```

Comment: Great - fixed it in one! Thank you